# How can I define a new group on an existent transient?

Tags: transient-library

I want to customize the forge-dispatch transient. Specifically I want to add new group, Remote, to the right side of Create. And add the new suffix there.

[image: forge-dispatch transient]

As far as I know, transient-{append,replace}-suffix all add a suffix in relation to an existing suffix. But I'm at a loss as to how *create* a new group in the existing transient. I'm guessing the solution would look something like the following:

```
  (transient-??? 'forge-dispatch "Remote"
    '("o" "Browse repository" forge-browse-remote))
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Care to provide some references?

Comment: I've added a brief description to the transient tag. All of magit menus are implemented using it. The photo shows the transient for the forge extension. I want to know how to add a new 'section' to the transient. ie. a new entry on the level of Fetch, List and Create under which I can add new commands.

Comment: Is this question related to magit? Should a "magit" tag be attached to the question? What is the "forge extension"? Should there be a "forge" tag added to the question? Adding more such information to your question will attract the right people (I'm obviously not the right person :-) ) to it who may be able to provide an answer, so it's better for you to be as explicit as possible.

Comment: The example is directly related to magit and forge, but the question is not. transient is a separate package that can (and is) be used outside of magit and magit and sibling projects like forge.